# Implicit conversion not working on lists c#

Tags: c#, list, interface

Take the following example :

```
     public interface IModel
    {
        public string FirstPropery { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model : IModel
    {
        public string FirstPropery { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Model> GetActualModels() 
    {
        var models = new List<Model>();

        models.Add(new Model
        {
            FirstPropery = "1"
        });

        models.Add(new Model
        {
            FirstPropery = "2"
        });

        return models;
    }


     public List<IModel> GetModels()
     {
        return GetActualModels();
     }
```

This does not compile, we have an error on GetModels()

```
"Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp1.Model>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp1.IModel>'"
```

Then if we change the function just a bit to :

```
 public List<IModel> GetModels()
 {
    var models = GetActualModels();

    var modelsInterface = new List<IModel>();

    modelsInterface.AddRange(models);

    return modelsInterface;
 }
```

This does not throw any compiling error. It must be a question answered many times but I have no idea how to search for the answer to it. Any ideas why this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function a bit to `Cast` every element in your list like this:

```
public static List<IModel> GetModels()
{
    return GetActualModels().Cast<IModel>().ToList();
}
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.